# Filter, count and sum in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, sum, countif, filtered-lookup

[image: 1]

In the data set above, instructors were surveyed to learn what are the best and worst workout according to them.
Using the sum and countifs together we realise that 2 yoga instructors believe that Yoga is the best form of workout, whereas a swimming instructor (Jaime) believes that swimming is a Poor form of workout.

I would now like to filter the data-set by age of response and then aggregate the results of the survey. If the response is New, then `SUM(CountIfs(BestWorkout,"[workout text]", Instructing, "[workout text]")`

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

Use **array formula** instead of `COUNTIFS()`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(IF($A$3:$A$6="new",IF(INSTRUCTING_IN=$B14,BEST_WORKOUT,""),"")=$B14,1,0))
```

After putting this formula, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then fill down